# How to Pass MapView to another activity

Tags: android

I have a mapview in one activity on which i drew a path, now i would transfer this mapview to another activity, how can i do?

Comment: why you need to transfer. Cant you make this mapView Global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really transfer controls that way: you'd have to do a remove() to undo the root view bindings and then hope and pray that it works when you re-add it, and to complicate things the MapView mixes in with the MapActivity in complex ways so this will probably fail.

See http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity.html. Notice the line that says

> Only one MapActivity is supported per
>   process. Multiple MapActivities
>   running simultaneously are likely to
>   interfere in unexpected and undesired
>   ways.

That means you probably can't do what you want.

Comment: +1: didn't know that multiple MapActivities might cause trouble... Thanks!